# What is a good bilingual (English-Hebrew) concordance of the Tanakh and Talmud?

Tags: product-recommendation, language, text

**Are there free online concordances of the Tanakh and the Talmud with hyperlinked text in English and Hebrew?**

I find such resources extremely helpful in the study of a language.

Here is an example: For the Quran, the [Quranic Arabic Corpus](http://corpus.quran.com/) is impressive: it has [grammatical analyses](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp) of every word or phrase as well as a [bilingual concordance with pronunciations](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=smw).

I am very interested in an analogous resource for the Tanakh and the Talmud, with English and Hebrew.

Comment: [This book](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/51322) and [this book](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/3365) are biblical concordances, and [this book](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/2932) and this two-volume set ([1](http://hebrewbooks.org/41580), [2](http://hebrewbooks.org/41581)) are concordances of the Talmud. However, none of them have English, nor are hyperlinked. You might want to try using those along with a dictionary, or checking the referred verses with an English translation.

Comment: LoS, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you can find what you need, and that you'll find other material on this site helpful as well.

Comment: Note that there's no canonical translation of _Tanach_ or the _talmud_. There isn't even a standard one of the _talmud_. (The JPS translation of _Tanach_ is fairly standard.)

Comment: @msh210 Soncino on Talmud?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's the oldest complete translation still in wide use, but I don't think I'd call it _standard_.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an iPhone, there is an exceptionally good app called [HebrewBible](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hebrewbible/id310104088?mt=8), by Bill Clementson. It has the BDB lexicon in it, but unlike BDB it also contains a full concordance. You can search by the first two root letters, and when you have found the word that you are looking for it will give you a listing of every verse in Tanakh that features that word, together with the relevant part of each verse.

(I appreciate that this only partially "answers" your question, since it is not online and it is not free. I apologise for that, but my answer is too long for a comment and I thought that this app might be of assistance to you anyway, or to other people who read your question.)

Comment: (Your whole first paragraph, including the link, actually does fit in a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing quite so helpful and immediately available as the QAC online... In terms of the Talmud, Jastrow's Dictionary of the Targumim and the Talmud is available for free online [here](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/), and while it may be somewhat out-of-date it is certainly a very useful resource.

For the TaNaKh, [the Christian site](http://www.blueletterbible.org/) you were linked to in the answer you got on the Biblical Hermeneutics board is a good place to find what the BDB says on a particular word or root. Again, the new HALOT lexicon is an amazing resource but it is [far from free](http://www.accordancebible.com/store/details/?pid=HALOT)... If you're looking to pay for apps, I think [Accordance](http://www.accordancebible.com/) is the way to go! There also appear to be some useful Christian apps [here](http://olivetree.com/bible-study-apps/).